# ASP.net, Compare textbox value with data table column value

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datatable

I want to compare the textbox value with a data table created in the session.
If the textbox value matches with the data table column item id, it should not allow to re enter that item on button click.

[image: Screen Shot]

```
protected void AddInGrid(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    messagelabel.Text = "";
    DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTabele"];
    DataRow drCurrentRow = null;

    if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0 & txtquantity.Text != "0" & checkstock()==true)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            //Creating new row and assigning values
            drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
            drCurrentRow["Item Id"] = Convert.ToInt32(txtid.Text);
            drCurrentRow["Item Name"] = txtname.Text;
            drCurrentRow["Price"] = Convert.ToInt32(txtprice.Text);
            drCurrentRow["Quantity"] = Convert.ToInt32(txtquantity.Text);
            drCurrentRow["Item Total"] = Convert.ToInt32(txttotalitemprice.Text);
        }

        //Removing initial blank row
        if (dtCurrentTable.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "")
        {
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[0].Delete();
            dtCurrentTable.AcceptChanges();
        }

        //Added New Record to the DataTable
        dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
        //storing DataTable to ViewState
        ViewState["CurrentTabele"] = dtCurrentTable;
        //binding Gridview with New Row
        gvGridview1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
        gvGridview1.DataBind();
    }
    else if (checkstock() == false)
    {
        messagelabel.Text = "Stock Not Enough";
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir, you can see in the provided screenshot. 
I donot want to enter "Butter" again in the data table. It should allow only one item in the grid with same id e.g (butter with id 12 ). And if user tries to enter again with id 12, it should show error.

Comment: I can see that but what have you tried to solve the problem ? I can't see any condition that tries to stop it, thats what i mean

Comment: foreach (GridViewRow rows in gvGridview1.Rows)
                        {
                            if (txtid.Text.Trim() != rows.Cells[0].Text.Trim())
                            {
                                dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                             
                                ViewState["CurrentTabele"] = dtCurrentTable;
                           
                                gvGridview1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                                gvGridview1.DataBind();
                            }

Comment: I used foreach loop to check rows and match it with item id textbox, but unfortunately it works for only one time. 
when i try to add for second time again. It adds that.